# Get current date time in bitbucket pipeline

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I have a simple question about bitbucket pipeline YAML script. I would like to use the current date and time as a variable in my pipeline, how to do that?

I tried:

```
pipelines:
  custom:
    build-docker-img:
      - variables:
          - name: MY_TAG
            default: $(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S)_$BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER
      - step:
          name: Build my image
          script:
            - docker build -t myname/myapp:$MY_TAG .
```

But when running the pipeline, bitbucket runner doesn't translate (neither understand) the `$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S)` to current date time value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by @N1ngu's answer, I solved the issue by:

```
pipelines:
  custom:
    build-docker-img:
      - step:
          name: Build my image
          script:
            - MY_TAG=${MY_TAG:-$(date +%Y-%m-%d)_$BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER}
            - docker build -t myname/myapp:$MY_TAG .
```

I can't use time due to the colon `:` makes it not a valid image tag.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding that value would require a shell and certain runtime so I doubt that could ever be defined as a default value for custom variables.

Just use shell tricks to assign that var a value if it is empty. If you need it in different steps, note the value would be always changing, so you should look into exporting it in an artifact file so you can load it in every step.

```yaml
pipelines:
  custom:
    build-docker-img:
      - variables:
          - name: MY_TAG
      - step:
          image: foo
          script:
            - MY_TAG=${MY_TAG:-$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S)_$BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER}
            - # ...
      - step:
          image: bar
          script:
            # Beware different value!
            - MY_TAG=${MY_TAG:-$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S)_$BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER}
            - # ...
```

Comment: Thanks, the `- variables: - name: MY_TAG` part pops up a dialog asking me to input the value when running the pipeline, that is not what I want. So, I removed it.